# How to query two tables with same schema but different time ranges in a date column

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have two tables:

```
main_products
old_products
```

They have the same info and schema with only one difference:

```
main_products has min(date) = 2022-01 and max(date) = 2022-05
```

and

```
old_products has min(date) = 2020-01 and max(date) = 2020-12
```

How can I query to get all records from `old_products + all records` from main_products to get products `from 2020-01 to 2022-05` ?

The product on both tables has and `product_id` field.

I tried to join both tables on `product_id` but the output is a table with twice number of columns.

```
select t1.*, t2.* from t1
inner join t2
one t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Don't add tags for databases not involved

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM t2
WHERE ...
```

If the columns in t1 and t2 are the same (same number of columns and same types), this will pull the data from both of them. Use `UNION` if you want duplicates removed or `UNION ALL` to include duplicates. (In your case it won't make a functional difference since the tables don't overlap by date, but `UNION ALL` will be faster.)

In the above example, you can put your condition (to only get 2022-01 to 2022-05) in both `WHERE` conditions. If you don't like repeating the condition, you can use the `UNION ALL` query in a subquery with the condition outside:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
 SELECT *
 FROM t1
 UNION ALL
 SELECT *
 FROM t2
) sq
WHERE ...
```